# How to tell hibernate.cfg.xml to get user,pass,url of database from a properties file inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Now I have to write user,pass,url of database twice. One in hibernate.cfg.xml and one inside a file called database.properties (used by Spring).

Is there a way to tell hibernate.cfg.xml to read the values inside database.properties?

I show you where these files are:
[image]

Comment: You don't. If you are using Spring don't use a `hibernate.cfg.xml`  and please ditch the `HibernateUtil`. Use Spring to configure and inject the Hibernate `SessionFactory`  instead.

Comment: Should I create a bean for the class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean and inject it?

Comment: Correct (or the `hibernate4` one depending on your hibernate version.).

Comment: Thank you. So far I used  a standard HibernateUtil class. Now that I follow your way, should I keep on doing these steps? 1) use .openSession() on the sessionFactory I injected 2) use .close() on the session I'm using? I don't know if spring itself handles someway these 2 steps.

Comment: Nope. use ` getCurrentSession()`  and let spring manage the session. That is explained in the Spring Reference Guide.

Comment: I have a doubt. When making a query like "select * from..." should I still use hibernateUtil class or should I handle it by using LocalSessionFactoryBean?

Comment: As stated ditch the `HibernateUtil` class. Delete it, burn it and never look at it again... Again I'm pointing you to the reference guide as how to execute queries is simply explained in there.

Comment: I'm reading it, but I still haven't found something that can help me with this doubt

Comment: Would be pretty useless for a framework if you would still need additional classes now wouldn't it. The `LocalSessionFactoryBean` produces a `SessionFactory`. To execute a query use `getCurrentSession` construct the query and execute it. Don't use the util class I cannot stress that enough. Work WITH the framework instead of trying to work around it, that will only complicate things.